# escape json string having double quotes

Tags: pandas, awk, sed

I have a json file with size in 500 MB with structure like

```
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"Jack "John","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
```

Issue is when i parse this string with pandas read_json, I get error

`Unexpected character found when decoding object value`

Issue is happening because of double quotes `"` in before `John` in first elecment of contact array.

Need help in escaping this quote either with sed/awk/python so that i can directly load the file in pandas.

**I am fine with ignoring contact with name as Jack as well but i can not ignore the complete row.**

Comment: Is it possible for you to have this quoted at generation time of JSON ? You almost need to write a parser for this, since it can get ugly pretty fast: `"name":"Jack "The big,ugly ripper" Johnson", "number":...`  Writing a regexp for that would be fairly hard.  Btw, in your example, you need to have a double quote AFTER John: `"name":"Jack "John""`

Comment: Data which i am getting is not generated by me or it can not be changed at source. So can you give me some regex to process it.

Comment: I just want to add a backslash in case any double quote comes in between name.

Answer (score 1):

In general here is no robust way to fix this, nor to ignore any part of the row nor even to ignore the whole row because if a quoted string can contain quotes and can also contain `:`s and `,`s then a messed up string can look exactly like a valid set of fields.

Having said that, if we target only the "name" field and assume that the associated string cannot contain `,`s then with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` we can do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/(.*"name":")(([^,"]*"[^,"]*)+)(".*)/,a) ) {
        gsub(/"/,"",a[2])
        $0 = a[1] a[2] a[4]
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"Jack O'Malley","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill Smith-Jones","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"X Æ A-12 Musk","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
```

I ran the above on this input file:

```
$ cat file
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"Jack "O'Malley","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack "Jill "Smith-Jones","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"X Æ A-12 "Musk","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
```

and you can do the same using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/"name":"([^,"]*"[^,"]*)+"/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-9)
        gsub(/"/,"",tgt)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART+7) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"Jack O'Malley","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill Smith-Jones","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"X Æ A-12 Musk","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill","number":"+1 232324789"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing that extra " using regex `("[\s\w]*)(")([\s\w]*")`.

The regex try to match any string with spaces/alphabets followed by a quote and then followed again by spaces/alphabets and removing that additional quote.

This will work for the given problem but for more complex patterns, you may have to tweak the regex.

Complete code:

```
import re

text_json = '{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"Jack "John","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill","number":"+1 232324789"}]}'
text_json = re.sub(r'("[\s\w]*)(")([\s\w]*")', r"\1\3", text_json )

print(text_json)
```

Output:

```
'{"user": "abc@xyz.com","contact":[{"name":"Jack John","number":"+1 23456789"},{"name":"Jack Jill","number":"+1 232324789"}]}'
```

Comment: Would the correct (desired) output here not be `{"name":"Jack \"John\"","number":"+1 23456789"}` ?  I believe original example missed an end quote after John.